# Compiler error for std::string in c++ builder XE3 project

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder-xe3

I am working on a service application in c++ builder XE3.
I am getting compiler error for std::string if I add this line:

```
string a = string("abcd") + "xyz";
```

Error output is as follows:

```
[bcc32 Error] string(141): E2285 Could not find a match for 'move<_Ty>(string)'
  Full parser context
string(140): decision to instantiate: string std::string + <char,char_traits<char>,allocator<char> >(string &&,const char *)
--- Resetting parser context for instantiation...
svcmain.cpp(21): #include C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\10.0\include\boost_1_39\boost\tr1\tr1\string
string(20): #include c:\program files\embarcadero\rad studio\10.0\include\../include/dinkumware/string
string(7): namespace std
string(140): parsing: string std::string + <char,char_traits<char>,allocator<char> >(string &&,const char *)
```

I tried to add  `#include <utility>`  just above `#include <string>` but still getting same error.
Instead, if I split the line into two as follows, it compiles without errors.

```
string a = string("abcd");
a += "xyz";
```

OR

```
string b = string("abcd");
string a = b + "xyz";
```

Its not practical to use this workaround as I have to use existing code which is getting large no of errors. Same code works without errors in other XE3 project.
Any ideas how to fix this error?

Comment: Are you using a `using namespace std` statement? Don't. Just fully qualify the `std` namespace in type declarations: `std::string a = std::string("abcd") + "xyz";` The error message suggests you are mixing Boost's `string` header with Dinkumware's `string` header, so you might have a namespace conflict.

Comment: I already tried that but still get the same error. I checked that none of the included header files has a `using namespace` statement.
Boost is not used at all.

Comment: "*Boost is not used at all*" - not according to your error message. `svcmain.cpp` is including `$(BDS)\include\boost_1_39\boost\tr1\tr1\string`, which in turn is including `$(BDS)include\dinkumware\string`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix in the other project. Setting the "backward compatibility" option to false fixed the error.
You can find the checkbox in - Project options -> C++ compiler -> Compatibility -> General.
This was initially set to true.